Set Lottie animation in background and don't increase the animation size
This is my animation.vue file
<template>
  <div class="snow-animation-container">
    <Vue3Lottie
      :animation-data="snowAnimation"
      :loop="true"
      style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 50%; height: 50%; z-index: -1;"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Vue3Lottie } from 'vue3-lottie';
import snowAnimation from '../images/SnowAnimation.json';

export default {
  components: {
    Vue3Lottie,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      snowAnimation,
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.snow-animation-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
</style>

Animation is rendering, but I want this animation to cover all the screen width.
use case is, I need to set a snow animation behind the popup so snow should cover the entire screen behind the popup.
